# How can I select / insert / update data from another table into a new table

Tags: sql, join, select, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table for categories like this - `nid` is an identity column:

**TB_Categories**

| nid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Brochure |
| 2 | stamp |

A specific number can be ordered for each category, such as:

`id` is identity

**TB_numbercategories**

| id | nid | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 |
| 4 | 2 | 100 |
| 5 | 2 | 500 |
| 6 | 2 | 1000 |

I have another table for countries - `cid` is an identity column:

**TB_Countries**

| cid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Germany |
| 2 | Netherland |
| 3 | Slovakia |

So far I have the contents and everything is fine.

The problem I have is that shipping costs vary for each issue of each category for each country.

For example: the order of the brochure is 100 different for Germany and Slovakia.
Or any other number for any other country.

I need a query that displays the data for me as follows:

| nid | country | number | transport_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Germany | 10 |  |
| 1 | Germany | 50 |  |
| 1 | Germany | 100 |  |
| 1 | Netherland | 10 |  |
| 1 | Netherland | 50 |  |
| 1 | Netherland | 100 |  |
| 1 | Slovakia | 10 |  |
| 1 | Slovakia | 50 |  |
| 1 | Slovakia | 100 |  |

I need a select query to display the information and just enter the shipping cost field.

I do this operation with Gridview .NET.

Thank you for your help in writing query for select and insert, update

Comment: Please elaborate on your needs, how TB_Countries is related to other tables? which table you are going to update and insert

Comment: You are right, I think it is better to have a table of countries with the id of the table TB_numbercategories foreign key, What do you think ?

Comment: Just make it clear,you need to define your table that is going to be updated from query

Comment: @iAm.Hassan sounds great it will be easier to display, for next time I suggest you to ask like a programmer/developer, don't make us to learn your functional side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema:**

> ```
> create table TB_Categories(nid    int, name varchar(20));
> insert into TB_Categories values(1,'Brochure');
> insert into TB_Categories values(2,'stamp');
>
>
> create table TB_numbercategories (id  int, nid    int, number int);
> insert into TB_numbercategories values(1,   1,    10);
> insert into TB_numbercategories values(2, 1,  50);
> insert into TB_numbercategories values(3, 1,  100);
> insert into TB_numbercategories values(4, 2,  100);
> insert into TB_numbercategories values(5, 2,  500);
> insert into TB_numbercategories values(6, 2,  1000);
>
> create table TB_Countries (cid    int, name varchar(20));
> insert into TB_Countries values(1,    'Germany');
> insert into TB_Countries values(2,    'Netherland');
> insert into TB_Countries values(3,    'Slovakia');
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> select tc.nid,tbc.name country ,number,'' Transport_cost from TB_Categories tc inner join TB_numbercategories tnc on tc.nid=tnc.nid
> cross join TB_Countries tbc 
> where tc.name='Brochure'
> order by tbc.name,number
> GO
> ```

**Output:**

> | nid | country | number | Transport_cost |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Germany | 10 |  |
> | 1 | Germany | 50 |  |
> | 1 | Germany | 100 |  |
> | 1 | Netherland | 10 |  |
> | 1 | Netherland | 50 |  |
> | 1 | Netherland | 100 |  |
> | 1 | Slovakia | 10 |  |
> | 1 | Slovakia | 50 |  |
> | 1 | Slovakia | 100 |  |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4f199171c74354bad819da3fb220ed5)*